# Unable to proceed with solving ODE using power series due to more than two terms in recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have to solve the following differential equation near ordinary point $x=0:$

$$\left(x^2-1\right)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+3x\,\frac{dy}{dx}+xy=0. $$

Proceeding with the method of power series I end up with

$$\sum a_{n-1}x^n+\sum(n(n-1)+3)a_nx^n-\sum(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n=0. $$

I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: Please do not use images, use mathjax, which is mainly LaTeX. You have an error in the coefficient for the first order derivative term. What is the actual task, find the general formula for the series coefficients or compute the first ... terms?

Comment: Show your work  and also indicate where you stuck ? @user463203

Comment: Do you have any initial conditions?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution**

We have the DE
$$\left(x^2-1\right)y''+3xy'+xy=0. $$
We let $y=\sum a_nx^n,$ so that
\begin{align*}
y&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\\
y'&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n x^{n-1}\\
y''&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}.
\end{align*}
Plugging this into the DE yields
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n}}_{\text{1st term: } x^2}-
\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}}_{\text{1st term: } x^0}+
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3n a_n x^{n}}_{\text{1st term: } x^1}+
\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+1}}_{\text{1st term: } x^1}=0.
$$
We break off terms in the second, third, and fourth sums so that the first term is $x^2,$ as in the first sum. Then we re-index. The result I get is as follows:
$$-2a_2-6a_3x+3a_1x+a_0x+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left[a_{j+1}+(j+2)(j+4)a_{j+2}-(j+4)(j+3)a_{j+4}\right]x^{j+2}=0. $$
Equating coefficients of like powers of $x,$ we obtain these three equations:
\begin{align*}
a_2&=0\\
a_0+3a_1-6a_3&=0\\
a_{j+1}+(j+2)(j+4)a_{j+2}-(j+4)(j+3)a_{j+4}&=0.
\end{align*}
Note that the second equation is consistent with the third, for $j=-1.$ 
Without more information, it would appear this is as far as we can go.